# Variable Value lost after pressing the "submit" button in PHP

Tags: php, forms, variables, submit

When Page_B is first run (by clicking the submit button on another page, Page_A) the value of variable SG (which is sent over from Page_A) is nicely printed. However, when I click the submit button on Page_B (which, correct me if I'm wrong, runs Page_B again), the printing space becomes empty. I conclude that the content (value) of SG has been DELETED as a result of the submit action. That is not what I want, as this value is needed  furtheron Page_B (code not yet written). How can I avoid this deleting from happening?

**Here is the code of Page_B:**

```
<html>

<?php

$SG=$_POST['SG'];
print ($SG);

?>

<form action="Page_B.php" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="trekking">
<input type="submit">

</form>

<?php

$T=$_POST['trekking'];
print ($T);

?>


</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "[the value] disappears"?

Comment: We're going to have to see the code of the form. Are you saving this as a hidden form entry?

Comment: can you please show the that submit code of the second page?

Comment: From the sound of this it seems you have multiple forms and you expect $_POST to encompass all of them instead of just the post values from the submitted form. Of course, we don't really know because you gave no sample code.

Comment: Sorry for not adding the code. I added it in my initial question. Thanks for the comments

Comment: your `$_POST['SG'];` experies after submit form, you have to add it into form e.g. in hidden input

Answer (score 6):

if you receive e.g. `$_POST['myvalue']` you have to post it through form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" value="<?= $_POST['myvalue'] ?>" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: put in the action ``thesamepage.php``

Comment: @doniyor action is optional. method, however, will default to GET if not defined. this answer was just updated so this comment isnt so useful anymore

Comment: you are right, but TavernSenses wanted this to be the same page thats why i mentioned, otherwise fine

Comment: Just FYI: "In HTML5, the action attribute is no longer required." [w3](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)

Comment: To avoid any sort of XSS attacks, I would strongly recommend wrapping every POST var outputted in HTML in `htmlspecialchars()` [man here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Thank you, but looks very complicated. Surely, there must be a more elegant solution, as almost any php structure with a submit button and multiple pages much encounter this problem.

Comment: you can post it through URL (GET parameter) or via SESSION scope

Comment: This isn't complicated at all. If you want to pass something through a POST, it has to be in the form. This means using hidden form entries. So if you got `$_POST['foo']` from the previous form, you simply include `<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="'.$_POST['foo'].'">`. The only other way to share information like this is in a GET (include in the action URL) or through sessions. Variables just don't magically stay alive through page loads like you think they do. :) And yes, every PHP structure with multiple forms encounters this, and it's not a problem.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew, for the sobering insight.